# OpenCart Wishlist

Tags: opencart

I'm trying to parse out the wishlist column in open cart's wishlist_to_store column to retrieve the product ID's.  At first glance I thought it was being stored as JSON, but that obviously not the case.  Is there a library or method I can use to parse it out?

Example wishlist:
a:2:{i:0;s:5:"16419";i:1;s:5:"16415";}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method you are looking to use is called [unserialize()](http://php.net/unserialize). This is fairly similar in function to what JSON does but is the PHP equivalent. You can use it as follows

```
$a = unserialize('a:2:{i:0;s:5:"16419";i:1;s:5:"16415";}');
var_dump($a);
```

Comment: Thanks!, is there a name for the serialized data type? What would I call it? (JSON,XML, etc)

Comment: Serialized data is about all you can call it